# rootView cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-fragments

Okay so i'm having an issue under: `rootView` in my code and the error it's causing: `rootView cannot be resolved to a variable` what could this mean? Do I have something wrong with my R. file? I'm using it within a fragment so could that be an issue as well?

The rest of the method:

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {

    private ListView myListView1;
    public String[] strListView; 


    public FragmentC() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);


        myListView1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        strListView = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_data_list);

        return rootView; 

        ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strListView);
        myListView1.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    }

}
```

I've only got an issue under both rootViews contained within this method, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a `return` statement in the beginning of your method and then again in the middle of your method which is just wrong. Return statement means that your method should finish and possibly return some sort of a value to its caller.

Please research a little bit what a `return` statement is.

[**`Here is a good starting read`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Secondly, you don't declare a variable called `rootView` anywhere but you are trying to use it. That is why the compiler gives you an error because `rootView` doesn't exist. Again, research how to create variables in Java.

[**`Here is another good starting read`**](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/local-variables-in-java.html)

Comment: Ok thanks i'm following a youtube example which I know it's a great way of doing things.